# Wsus client getting error 403 (0x80244018)

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, windows-10, windows-update, wsus

It's been a week that my clients can't download updates from my wsus server.
They control and find updates normally but when it comes to download them, they are all getting 403 error from the server.
Here the log file entry:

```
2023/03/20 08:55:33.7366979 12264 1424  DownloadManager DO job {FB5BA17F-944D-4569-84F0-58FF9E125F57} failed, updateId = 93C74394-F400-4CF4-B49D-B750156013E0.201, hr = 0x80190193. File URL = https://xxxxxx:8531/, local path = C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\ae4be6f6193482f51b7b4289ad4c2931\34acd51e6ca1c835eacff757d6ea75c4a22ad3cb, The response headers = HTTP/1.1 403   Date: Mon, 20 Mar 2023 07:55:31 GMT  Content-Length: 1233  Content-Type: text/html  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0  x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

I already tried  to reset wsus but nothing changed even with deleting the wsus-administration site.
The file https://xxxxxx:8531/selfupdate/iuident.cab is downloaded correctly.
I also tried to set wsus for not store files locally.
Google not helped me neither.

Comment: On a real world server, there can be too many things breaking IIS. Enable FRT and see what gives you 403, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing and then you can get started from there.

Comment: FRT get me to directory module, so I enabled directory listing and the error I get changed to 0x80d05001, iis reply always status 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what it was, but I installed the update manually on the clients and the issue is gone.
The update installed was the march 2023 cumulative update ([KB5023773](https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/topic/21-marzo-2023-kb5023773-build-del-sistema-operativo-19042-2788-19044-2788-e-19045-2788-preview-5850ac11-dd43-4550-89ec-9e63353fef23))