# Windows Update Service gets stuck at Stopping state whenever I check for update on the domain controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, windows-update

On my domain controller which is Running Windows Server 2016, whenever I check for updates, the updates start downloading and get stuck at 7% or sometimes stuck at checking for updates. I see that the Windows Update service goes from running to stopping. I rebooted multiple times.

```
net stop wuauserv /yes
net stop cryptSvc /yes
net stop bits /yes
net stop msiserver /yes
ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver
rmdir /S /Q C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.old
rmdir /S /Q C:\Windows\System32\Catroot2.old
```

I executed the commands and when I manually checked for updates, the updates were downloading but stuck at 8% and I now see that the Windows update service is back to Stopping state along with Update Orchestrator Service for Windows Update.

I also mounted Windows Server ISO image and ran `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /LimitAccess /Source:D:\sources\install.wim`

It didn't give me any error after running but still the problem persists. The updates are stuck in "Checking for updates" and the Windows update service is stuck in Stopping state.

We have two Domain Controllers. I have daily backups from Veeam but I am hesitant to restore a DC from backup. I am not sure what would happen to AD database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to donwload and install maually the latest SSU update:
[KB5023788: Servicing stack update for Windows Server 2016: March 14, 2023](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5023788-servicing-stack-update-for-windows-server-2016-march-14-2023-4c39b60e-f919-42c6-93af-7799f0b7f57c)

Comment: That update is not installing.

Comment: That too remains stuck or it throw an error?

Comment: The servicing stack update finally installed but when I check for updates, it's trying to download the May update but failing with `There were problems downloading some updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this, try searching the web or contacting support for help. This error code might help: (0x8024a10a)`

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue ([Wsus client getting error 403 (0x80244018)](https://serverfault.com/questions/1127245/wsus-client-getting-error-403-0x80244018)).
I resolved by installing the update that gave me the error (in my case march 2023) manually.